# Json, weird Bugs for parse for Xcode

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode

I need to mention something before i explain the bugs.

- The JSON format is valid, and the code has works fine also.
- when i pull the data from the server, the data SOMETIME will got error.

When i try to NSLog the return, and below is the error return.

```
Error parsing JSON: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unterminated string around character 2424.) UserInfo=0x956f200 {NSDebugDescription=Unterminated string around character 2424.}
```

On my Iphone 4, it works fine. But it will always fail to get data Xcode SDK or Iphone 5s, even all is running the same apps.

This this i upload is the return data(just show you how huge data for the return).
[image: JSON Image]

```
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data > %@",returnString);
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSError *thiserror;

NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &thiserror];
parseData = (NSDictionary *) [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &thiserror];
if (!jsonArray) {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", thiserror);
}
```

- On the returnString nslog, it had return the complete data.
- On the jsonArray, it always go false, means will display the error

Now i trying to assume because the json is too large, so the connection speed will make the return be error. but i not really got idea how to solve it. Is that i looking on wrong direction? or any one can give me hints how to solve this problem? thanks!

Comment: Why are you creating both an array and a dictionary with the same json data?

Comment: When you get the error, copy paste the JSON in [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) and you will see where and what the error is. Probably there's a unescaped quote somewhere.

Comment: @rckoenes , as i mention early, this JSON is valid. and it will fine on sometimes. means in the same moment, My iphone 4 works fine but my Xcode SDK not working.

Comment: @Fogmeister , jsonArray is for checking. and ParseData is for return to the the scene for future use.

Comment: Well the error from the JSON parser is that there is an unterminated string some where in the JSON. This mostly means that there is  JSON node liele `"message" = "Wow this "really" works "` which should ofcourse be `"message" = "Wow this \"really\" works "`.

Comment: @rckoenes , i think this part already did. example return >> "title": "No \"Summertime Sadness\" for Birthday Girl Lana Del Rey Today | style file | Style.com".
is that still got any optional possible? for this error return? thanks. because same like i mention just now, even json return, work fine on my test device, but fail to get on xcode sdk.

Comment: You keep talking about xcode sdk, are you write a plugin for Xcode? Since the JSOn parsing is work on a physical device I think you mean that if does not work on the simulator. If so then remove the Xcode tag.